# Rails Active Record Order Issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model class named Event, and a field 'when'. I'm trying to return events order by when desc, so here is the code.

```
@events = Event.order("'when' DESC")
```

I'm using MySQL as the database. but the **returned results is not sorted**.

I've looked into the console, and file the generated sql, which seems ok

```
SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` ORDER BY 'when' DESC
```

and I also run this sql in console, and it returned sorted result. Is anything special with 'when'?

if I changed my query to `Event.order("events.when DESC")`, then it returned a sorted result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be backtick, not single quote.

```
@events = Event.order("`when` DESC")
```

when you use `single quote` around `when` it is not a column anymore but merely a string value. you should have use backtick instead of single when *escaping* tableName and columnName.

Comment: I'm not even sure if you really need the quotes/backticks surroung 'when', just `Event.order('when DESC')` should do the trick. At least, it works for me

Comment: @KuyaJohn it's not optional, it's not optional, I got a sql syntax error if no backticks.

Comment: @MrYoshiji backtick, *i think*, is needed here because `WHEN` is present on the list of [**MySQL Reserved Word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the single quotes you are adding to the field. It should work with quotes around the whole thing such as:

```
@events = Event.order("column_name DESC")
```

This is true in general for column_names, except in your case where `when` is a reserved word.  So you then need to backtick it:

```
 @events = Event.order("`when` DESC")
```

But still, I'd recommend changing your column name, you'll eventually run into complications using a reserved word. `when` is also not very descriptive in my opinion, is it: When the event was created/ordered? When the event will begin? When the event will end?  Perhaps a `occurring_at` or `date_occurring` column name would be more detailed.

Comment: `WHEN` is present on the list of [**MySQL Reserved Word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: Ah! good to know. In that case @Jun1st it may be best to rename your column.  I'll edit my answer accordingly ^^

Comment: @joofsh actually, no intent to change it. "when" make sense to the model :)

Comment: @Jun1st Good code takes readability into account. Its your code so I trust that you know what makes sense to the model. "When" may make sense to you because you wrote it, but will it be obvious what is meant to another developer who sees the code for the first time? But  just my 2 cents :)

Comment: @joofsh what does "when" means to you?

Comment: I wrote in my original answer 3 possible meanings. Let's say its safe to assume its "when the event is occurring". But then it's probably a date with a separate time column? Or no its probably the time of day its occurring. Or wait is it date+time together? It's just very vague, and I personally prefer/recommend more descriptive column names (logic which extends to method and instance variable naming).

Comment: @joofsh what if there are already applications accessing the database? Would you still recommend to change the column name and recode the compiled application?